# Macro not running when on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 macros and a button that combines those macros. The button is on Sheet1 and the macros are built for functions on Sheet2 & Sheet3. When I click the button, Macro1 works but I get an error when Macro2 tries to run. I tried to run Macro2 while on Sheet2 and it works but I get the same error when I try to manually run it while on Sheet1. The error code is:

"Run-time error '1004': AutoFill method of Range class failed"

I don't have an end cell range for my autofill "C2:ET" because my values in column A are never the same amount, could have 4 values could have 600. Macro2 autofills my formula in row C2:ET2 based on the values in column A.

Can someone help me figure out the issue? Thanks in advance.

Macro1

```
Sub Master()
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim trg As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long


Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")


src.Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Macro2

```
Sub MasterFormulaPop()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:ET2").AutoFill Range("C2:ET" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub
```

BUTTON MACRO:

```
Sub PopulateMaster()
Call Master 'Macro1
Call MasterFormulaPop 'Macro2
End Sub
```

Comment: That's because the `Range` calls in `Range("C2:ET" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` need qualified with `Worksheets("Sheet2").` Can''t hurt to qualify `Rows` as well.

Comment: @BigBen How do I qualify? Sorry, I'm not sure what that means. I'm basically crash learning this so I'm not too familiar with all the terms.

Comment: Write Worksheets("Sheet2") in front of the Range.

Comment: Surely would be better to put the contents of `MasterFormulaPop` at the end of the `Master` sub (before the `End Sub` line).  You can then reference the worksheet using `trg`: `trg.Range("C2:ET2").AutoFill trg.Range("C2:ET" & trg.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`